# f2py recovering variables from Fortran module

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

My endgame is to have take a number of different Fortran scripts that I've written and interface them via Python.  The scripts themselves are relatively straightforward: essentially, just a lot of math without any programming structures more complicated than arrays.  However, I'm pretty new to this, so I have a small test script that I'm trying it out on.

The main script is below (in abbreviated form):

```
subroutine addwake
use geometry
implicit none

   integer::i,j,k,m
   real(kind=8),allocatable::xn2(:,:),yn2(:,:),zn2(:,:)
   real(kind=8)::avg,m1,m2,m0
   character(50)::namefile

!f2py intent(out) i,j,k,m
!f2py intent(out),allocatable xn2,yn2,zn2
!f2py intent(out) avg,m1,m2,m0
!f2py intout(out) namefile

! Check if surface node arrays are allocated
if(allocated(xn))then
   deallocate(xn,yn,zn)
end if

! Read in sectional point distribution

...

end subroutine addwake
```

This utilizes a module (geometry.f95) that is the source of my grief.

```
module geometry
    implicit none

    ! panel coordinates and connectivity
    integer::jmax,kmax
    integer::npts_wake
    real(kind=8)::dspan
    real(kind=8),allocatable::xn(:,:),yn(:,:),zn(:,:)
    !f2py intent(out) jmax,kmax,npts_wake
    !f2py intent(out) dspan
    !f2py intent(out),allocatable xn,yn,zn
end module geometry
```

I compile the code directly via `f2py -c -m wake geometry.f95 addwake.f95` and then go into the Python interpreter to run it.  It runs fine, giving me the expected output (a text file with ordered lists of numbers), but then I try to extract variable values, which is what I'll need to be able to do in my integration framework.  When I try that, I get the following results:

```
>>> print wake.geometry.xn
[[ 2.01331785  2.01331785  2.01331785  2.01331785  2.01331785]
 [ 2.00308232  2.00308232  2.00308232  2.00308232  2.00308232]
 [ 1.99284679  1.99284679  1.99284679  1.99284679  1.99284679]
 ..., 
 [ 0.979798    0.979798    0.979798    0.979798    0.979798  ]
 [ 0.989899    0.989899    0.989899    0.989899    0.989899  ]
 [ 1.          1.          1.          1.          1.        ]]
>>> print wake.geometry.yn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: yn
>>> print wake.geometry.zn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: zn
```

If I change the f2py declaration in geometry.f95 such that each variable is defined on its own line, I get the attribute error for all three variables.  I'm pretty stumped here, so any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this doesn't give any sort of explanation for *why* the posted doesn't work, but it does provide a temporary solution.  If I just omit the f2py declarations for the allocatable variables in geometry.f95 (the module), everything is hunky dory.  In other words:

```
module geometry
    implicit none

    ! panel coordinates and connectivity
    integer::jmax,kmax
    integer::npts_wake
    real(kind=8)::dspan
    real(kind=8),allocatable::xn(:,:),yn(:,:),zn(:,:)
!f2py intent(out) jmax,kmax,npts_wake
!f2py intent(out) dspan

end module geometry
```

...enables me to use the interpreter to pull values for all three matrices.  In trying to pull values for the other variables (jmax, kmax, etc.), I am, however, unsuccessful.  Something about these variable declarations muddles the works, apparently, and I'm not sure why.